# use global reference inside nested functions

Tags: python

I got an error at the while, that the name 'start' is not defined, although I declared it as global inside the nested one, I know that there is another approach is to changed the signature of the function of BS to take the start and end variables, but I need to know how to solve it using the global approach, Thanks!

```
class math:
    def search(self,nums,x):
        start = 0
        end = len(nums)

        def BS():
            global start
            global end

            while(start<=end):
                #i assign  here  a new value to start and end

        first = BS()
        return first
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nonlocal`, so something like:

```
class math:
    def search(self,nums,x):
        start = 0
        end = len(nums)

        def BS():
            nonlocal start
            nonlocal end

            while(start<=end):
                pass # use pass if you want to leave it empty!
                #i assign  here  a new value to start and end

        first = BS()
        return first
```

Maybe you'll find [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) helpful!

Comment: Exactly.  @Flupper, the reason this works is because, when you first defined `start`, Python treated it as local to the `search` function.  When, in the `BS` function, you declared `global start`, Python assumed that this must be a different variable from the previous instance of `start` because that one wasn't global.

Comment: Thank you guys, finally got it, it took me some time to know this reason.

Comment: @Flupper Do you mind accepting the answer if it helps! Thanks

Comment: I immediately accepted it after you submitted the answer, but I got an error message that I should wait more time to accept it, then I forgot, thank you for remembering me it!